# How to pass variables from Main Activity to AsynTask and along its methods? 

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, parameter-passing, scope

I use AsyncTask to call a web service and edit its response.

I call my Task like this:

```
new CallWebService().execute(et.getText().toString().trim());
```

where et is an EditText where the user gives his phone number(String).So i pass a string parametre to the execute method.

Then in my CallWebService class that extends the AsyncTask i take the given string and use it as parametre for the Web Service call:

```
private class CallWebService extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object>
```

the code of the doInBackround method:

```
        @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... phone) {
        Object result = null;

        try {

            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    // if i put "6949861372" manually at the second parametre it works!

            request.addProperty("phone", phone);
            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            result = envelope.getResponse();
        } catch (Exception e) {
                    //do nothing
        }
        return result;
    }
```

If i put "6949861372" manually at the second parametre ((String) phone)it works!So what is wrong here?
So how can i pass the given number from the editText to the doInBackground method?

I can't figure it out!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the Parameter by,

```
String phoneNumber = phone[0];
```

inside `doInBackground()` method then you can use this phoneNumber as parameter as below,

```
request.addProperty("phone", phoneNumber);
```

Comment: I don't understand.The parametre tha i need,is in an EditText.So is wrong this code?new CallWebService().execute(et.getText().toString().trim());

Comment: No, but as you are passing it to AsyncTask you will get the parameter like I stated.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the code inside your try block into doInBackground() method. ProgressDialog should be shown from onPreExecute. When you catch an Exception you should call publishProgress(). And overrride your onProgressUpdate(). You put code for dissmising Dialog and showing Toast there

Comment: i do that but it shows me that the application must force close.Is the problem that i use at the doInBackground() toast messages?How can i pass the result object (is the response from the web service ) to the postExecute()?

Comment: can you give the log? And also showing Toasts inside doInBackground() won't work. You must do it in onProgressUpdate(). You can call publishProgress with different parameters. And upon that you know which Toast you should show